# Choosing what loads in external browser on iOS app

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed an app running in query mobile and phonegap. There are two parts to the app, both pulling data from an external database for ease of updating. The two areas are movies and content. The movies are streamed from youtube and the content is text pulled from the external database and displayed as a mini webpage.

Everything works fine, apart from the movies page which lists all the movies (with a small preview image) redirects to youtube, opening the first video in the list. Adding:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http://"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https://"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

To the app delegate.m file solves this issue, but creates another. The content that is pulled from the database in the second part of the app, has a few links to external webpages, we want these to be opened up in safari to give the user the best viewing possibilities, but even though the link have target="_blank" they still open up in the app, due to the overriding code above.

Is there anyway to search for youtube links rather than http || https?

Hope this explains my problem, and any help welcome on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, changing the code to check for www.youtube.com first solves the issue. Luckily all the links within the app go to m.youtube.com, so this gets around the problem of thee not forwarding ;)

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    if ([[url host] isEqualToString:@"www.youtube.com"]){
        return YES;
    } else if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http://"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https://"]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }  
}
```